# ui:repeat id & jsf dataTable & primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

**JSF Datatable**

```
  <ui:repeat var="folioVO" value="#{myBean.folioList}" id="folioTable">
              <h:dataTable id="promotion_dataTable" var="articlePromo"
              value="#{folioVO.lstArticles}" >
               ...<
              </h:dataTable>
    </ui:repeat>
```

In this case, the datatable id which gets generated is : **folioTable:ui repeat number:promotion_dataTable**

**Primefaces datatable:**

```
   <ui:repeat var="folioVO" value="#{myBean.folioList}" id="folioTable">
      <p:dataTable id="promotionDetail_dataTable" var="articlePromo"
      value="#{folioVO.lstArticles}" >
       ...
      </p:dataTable>
    </ui:repeat>
```

In this case, the datatable id which gets generated is : **folioTable:promotion_dataTable**

Since the repeat id ìs not getting appended in case of primefaces datatable, All the jquery /javascript gets applied to the first table.

How can this be done ..?

Thanks

Comment: check this [Why doesn't h:dataTable inside ui:repeat get correct ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002555/components-are-with-the-same-id-inside-uirepeat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked:

```
<p:dataList var="folioVO" value="#{myBean.folioList}" id="folioTable">
  <p:column>
     <p:dataTable id="promotionDetail_dataTable" var="articlePromo"
      value="#{folioVO.lstArticles}" >
       ...
      </p:dataTable>
    </p:column> 
</p:dataList>
```

Comment: please mark this as correct answer, will help someone searching in future

Comment: @mprabhat: own answers can only be accepted 48h after the question is asked.